# Dojo build package configuration

Tags: javascript, dojo, amd

In our Dojo system, we have something like the following specified in our dojoConfig:

```
packages: [{
    name: "myWidgets",
    location: "/js/libs/widgets"
}]
```

So that in our require statements, all we have to do is something like:

```
 require(["myWidgets/myCalendarWidget"....
```

The problem is when I run the build, this dojoConfig is not available and I get numerous missing dependency errors because 'myWidgets' isn't defined according to the build profile.

Now, I've tried adding a package block to the build profile also, but the end result of that is to create an actual 'myWidgets' package, which I don't want.

So, is there any way to make the build see the definition of the 'myWidgets' alias, yet have the end result of the build output still mirror the regular file structure (i.e. /js/libs/widgets)?  I tried to define these path aliases in the defaultConfig element in the build profile and that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a profile, you can specify the packages in the profile

```
/util/buildscripts:./build.sh profile=../../../myProfile.js
```

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/build/buildSystem.html#profile-basics

You can also specify a javascript file that holds the dojoConfig

```
/util/buildscripts:./build.sh --dojoConfig ../build/examples/dojoConfig.js
```

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/build/buildSystem.html#using-a-package-configuration

---

Answer to your comment.  The path is relative from where dojo.js is.

```
var dojoConfig = {
    parseOnLoad: true,
    isDebug: true,
    locale: 'en-us',
    paths: {
        "evf":      "../../evf"
    }
};
```

My directory structure looks like

```
js/dojo-1.8.0
  dijit
  dojo <-- contains dojo.js
  dojox
  util
js/evf
  myCustomWidget.js
```

Comment: I've tried that actually using a profile and a dojoConfig file on the command line.  The end result is that I have no missing dependency errors, but the myWidgets packages are created again at the project root.

What is the difference between the 'packages' property in the build profile vs. the 'packages' property in the dojoConfig?

Comment: I don't see any may to output to somewhere else.  You will have to manually copy the files.

Comment: Are we using the packages property in dojoConfig incorrectly then?  I tried using 'paths' and that didn't work either.  I just need something in dojoConfig that specifies an alias for a path, but that doesn't try to create a package for that at build time.

Comment: Yes paths in the dojo config is what you want.  The path will be relative from dojo.js.  See my edit

Comment: I am using paths in the dojoConfig now and that isn't working either.  I am passing a config file to the --dojoConfig command line switch.  Inside that file, the path I'm using for myWidgets is an absolute path from the root.  If I specify /path/to/myWidgets does that look from the root of the filesystem or some other root? (project root perhaps)

Comment: If you don't want want to build the package, then don't specify it at build time.